# use define_method to create a method with equal on console

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I've this

```
ALIAS = %w{a b c}
ALIAS.each do |shortcode|
  define_method("#{shortcode}=") do |value|
    puts "CALLING THE ASSIGNMENT METHOD"
    eval "$#{shortcode} = value"
  end
end
```

I executed that on a Pry console, and then do:

```
a = 123
```

I end with an `a` variable that contains `123`, but my method doesnt get called.

if I do instead

```
self.a = 123
```

My method is called.

Is there any way to make it work without self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you have an expression

```
x.y=z
```

the Method "y=" is invoked on the object x, with the argument z.

However, if you have an expression

```
y=z
```

y is interpreted as the name of a variable, and gets assigned the value z.

Since you want the a= method to be invoked, you need a receiver. While we often can leave out the receiver, if it is 'self', Ruby can't recognize here that you want to do a method invocation. Hence you have to explicitly use 'self'.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make it work with self?

Do you mean without self?

No. You have to use self.